# How to change background of date with jquery datepicker?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

Why doesn't the CSS code in the jquery.ui.datepicker.css work? I thought that it might be something in the jquery.ui.theme.css file since I used jQuery themeroller, but it wasn't. Firebug apparently sent me to the correct lines of the right files, but I can't seem to fix it. Would anyone be kind enough to try giving firebug a shot right [here](http://www.sportannica.com/schedule.php)?

Comment: Please check http://imgur.com/FtZdv. If you wanted this sort of background change, then further details would be shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining a css background color and a css background image, the image will show above the color.  In this case, for example, line 26 references url(images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png) for the background image.  If you were to modify that image, or take the image off and simply use the background color it would work.

Comment: Let me use SSH real quick and give it a try. I'll let you know once I'm done. Thanks

Comment: Nope. Didn't change a thing. As you can see with firebug now, I changed the background to red and got rid of the url to the image. But, it's still the same.

Comment: It looks quite red to me, was the css cached for you, or perhaps you're making other changes.

Comment: Shit. Gotta switch to chrome incognito. Firefox always does this to me when I'm not using private browsing